# Trailing breakpoints in VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

Does anyone know if there is a way or plugin that allows you to create a trailing breakpoint while debugging. For example I want to set a breakpoint on some class and then as I step to the next line and my breakpoint gets updated to that line. Then step to the next line and my breakpoint gets updated to that line, etc... This would be really useful when diving deep into a class hierarchy and being able to start debugging again at the same point where I stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Just toggle the breakpoint whenever you want it, since you're stepping through the code anyway.

I don't see a lot of value in this, but the F9 (for toggling breakpoint) and F10 (for stepping to the next line) keys are right next to one another.

To debug, just:

1. Set the breakpoint on the first line of code you want to hit.
2. When the breakpoint hits for the first time, use F9 to remove the breakpoint (if desired).
3. Press F10/F11 to step to (or into) the next line.

I don't see much value when you keep moving the breakpoint, unless you keep breakpoints there along the hierarchy.